# Managed package batch failing to execute with error CPU time limit exceeded

Tags: apex, batch

I am trying to understand why managed package batch is failing. From the below screenshot, can we assume that it failed in the start method itself? or entered first iteration of execute method and failed?

[image]

**NOTE**: I already reached out to managed package vendor and this question is about trying to understand where it could be failing(start or execute method).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the start method timed out. Since there were zero total batches, this seems to imply that it never got as far as a single execute method or finish method. You will need the vendor to use ISV debugging, but that should give you a starting point to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a managed package you will need to work with the app vendor to see if they have License Management Application set up so that they can log in and take some logs.

From the above screenshot it sounds like it failed on the first execution of the batch or the start method.That is it went into the first execute method and seems like this where it hit the CPU limit or it might be on start method.

One need logs or code to be sure of what is causing the failure.

Comment: Yes, I reached out to vendor and this is more of my way of understanding where it could be failing.

Based on your answer, start method finished successfully then why Total Batches column shows zero. Shouldn't it show the actual number of batches?

Comment: Ya i am not sure why it says 0 there but it also says it processed 1 batch and failed a batch. This could be in start method itself as well or first execute method. Without looking at logs its hard to make a guess